# jQuery Slide Toggle Affects Multiple Divs

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

i'm currently trying to implement a slide toggle on a repeatable block of code. Once the trigger is clicked it opens up a comments panel. At the moment it is opening all of the panels - i have searched around but most of the solutions target next sibling or parent which i can't seem to get to work as its not a direct descendant.

The jquery so far looks like this.

```
$('.SlideToggle').click(function() { 
  $('.SlideComments').stop().slideToggle('fast', function() {      
    $('.SlideComments').toggleClass('active', $(this).is(':visible'));
  });
});
```

The HTML block looks like this.

```
<div class="col-100 feed-item">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-1 profile-pic">
<a href="<?php echo ROOT; ?>">
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo ROOT; ?>images/example-profile.jpg">
</a>
</div><!-- col-md-1 -->

<div class="col-md-11">
<span class="feed-name clearfix">Leonardo Dicaprio</span>
<span class="feed-time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 23 Minutes Ago</span>
<p>Hi, I am selling a Complete Core/Skeleton for a Mermail Deck. Anyone interested? Let me know....</p>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="col-100 feed-actions-container">
<ul class="feed-actions clearfix">
<li><a href="<?php echo ROOT; ?>" title="Like">Like</a></li>
<li class="SlideToggle">2 Comments</li>
<li><a href="<?php echo ROOT; ?>" title="Share">Share</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo ROOT; ?>" title="Report">Report</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="row SlideComments">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<ul class="feed-comments">
<li>
<span class="feed-name clearfix">Steven Ball</span>
<p>Awesome!!! let me know how much...?</p>
</li>
<li>
<span class="feed-name clearfix">Richard Carpenter</span>
<p>Why don't you just create an auction?</p>
</li>                                           
</ul>

<form role="form" class="leave-comment">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="LeaveComment">Leave Comment</label>
<textarea class="form-control common" id="LeaveComment" name="LeaveComment" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Post Comment</button>
</form>                                                                 
</div><!-- col-xs-12 -->
</div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- feed actions -->                                                     
</div><!--col-xs-12 -->
</div><!-- row -->                                              
</div><!-- col-md-11 -->
</div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- feed item -->
```

The trigger is located on the list item within feed-actions-container (li.SlideToggle) the panel which needs to slide open is .SlideComments - and as i said above this block of code will be repeated multiple times.

Many thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: JsFiddle - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qkhq0qt4/)

Comment: Bump! can anyone help me?